# How to use Instr in VBA to find a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a macro that will tell me where in the worksheet is the terms "Rep 1" "Rep 2"

I am new to VBA and am trying to write this at my internship. I have tried to use a get function but it is not working. I found the Instr function and was curious about how to implement it into my code.

```
Sub Value()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim Char As Integer
    For Each rCell In Selection
    CharCount = Len(rCell)
    Char = InStr(1, rCell, "(")
    rCell.Characters(1, Char - 1).Font.Bold = True
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

This is just an example of what I would like to do.[Data I Am Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGLOg.png)

Comment: You could just use `Find()`? e.g. `Dim fCell as Range / Set fCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="Rep 1")`?

Comment: You could also use conditional formatting to highlight it...the rule could just be `=A1="Rep 1"`...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Find function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Using a wildcard operator *, this code will find all values that start with Rep (so it covers both, Rep1 and Rep2).
Sets all matches to bold.

```
Set Results = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Rep*", LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Results Is Nothing Then
   firstAddress = Results.Address
   Do
        Results.Font.Bold = True
        Set Results = ActiveSheet.Cells.FindNext(After:=Results)
    Loop While Not Results Is Nothing And Results.Address <> firstAddress
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the selected cells and "bold-ing" the cells with "Rep 1" in it is a possible solution:

[image]

```
Sub BoldValue()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim char As Long

    For Each myCell In Selection
        If InStr(1, myCell, "Rep 1") > 0 Then
            myCell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```